# How to create a child domain with LDAPS when the parent domain is non-SSL?

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, subdomain

Is it possible to create a child domain with SSL enabled? If so how can I achieve this? The parent domain does NOT have SSL enabled but it is not possible to change it to enable SSL. So I would like to create a child domain with SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not SSL is available on a domain controller is a function of whether or not you have a valid certificate on the DC that is a) not expired, b) has the FQDN of the server in the subject or the first SAN and c) has the Server Authentication EKU.

I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to do this on the parent domain. Adding a child domain just to have a couple DCs with LDAP/S available seems pretty wasteful to me.

Comment: thank you for the info. I was planning to use this child domain to test some functionality in our product and plan to delete it later. Is there a site that I can refer to know more about what the whole LDAP SSL deal is?

Comment: Take a look at this KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321051 for the nuts and bolts. Adding/removing child domains, while not destructive or anything, is probably not something I'd make a habit of doing in production for this type of activity.

Comment: I am reading through the doc, but one further question. If I install a certificate on the parent domain (that's what SSL seems to be all about) will it effect any existing functionality of the AD?

Comment: No. Windows doesn't use LDAP/S for anything.